# Uncaught TypeError: t is not a function at onSubmit ReactJS Hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, react-hooks

I'm passing the closePopup function through props. This function works, but I get the error in the console.

My component

```
function FormSearch({ closePopup }) {
  const submitSearch = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    closePopup();
  };
}
```

My function to close popup in another component.

```
function MobileProvider() {
const [showPopup, setShowPopup] = useState(false);

  const closePopup = () => {
    setShowPopup((prev) => !prev);
  };
}
```

I hope to solve this problem by passing the function via props. so that the error in the console does not look further.

Detail. When clicking, the popup closes normally, I just don't understand why the error appears in the console.

Comment: Actually passing function through props might not be the way, What you should be doing is to manage the state globally and access them (Have a look at ```useContext```, ```useReducer```), Not keep passing them through function props.

Comment: Please show how you are passing the `closePopup` prop to the `FormSearch` component

Comment: Sorry for only replying now, it's been pretty hectic around here.

So I have a form with a submit button, here I pass the closePopup inside that function.

This form is a separate component.

On another screen, I import the form into the popup. the closePopup belongs to this component and not the form component.

Reinforcing. Then I pass the closePopup function that belongs to the popup component inside the form's onSubmit.